# How do I add grid lines to Chartify plots?

Tags: chartify

How do I add grid lines to a Chartify plot?

This is what my code looks like:

```py
ch = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True, x_axis_type="linear")
ch.plot... (plotting my data)
ch.show("png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Chartify uses Bokeh, which means you can style components using Bokeh attributes.

You can add grid lines by setting the `grid_line_color` for the `ygrid` and `xgrid`:

```
ch.figure.ygrid.grid_line_color = "#ECECEC"
ch.figure.xgrid.grid_line_color = "#ECECEC"
```